# HUnit testing with file dependent tests

Tags: haskell, io, monads, hunit

I have a lexer, and wish to test it against a set of known good test cases. These are held in a subdirectory **./test_src/** , and each has an extension ***testname*.txt**

What i'd like to do is get the paths to all relevant test cases:

```
getTestFiles :: IO [FilePath]
find always (extension ==? ".txt") "/path/to/test_src/"
```

and create a HUnit TestList containing HUnit TestCases each with an assertion created via a function along the lines of

```
testMyLexer :: IO FilePath -> Assertion
```

something along the lines of

```
myTest :: [IO FilePath] -> Test
myTest = TestList $ fmap TestCase $ fmap testMyLexer
```

where I seem to be failng in my approach is that this seems to first require the follwoing function, and then mapping over its result:

```
unableToDoThis :: IO [FilePath] -> [IO FilePath]
```

I've a strong suspicion the approach I'm following is impossible, as it seems to require escaping the IO Monad, so what I'm asking is:

1. is this approach viable, if so what am I missing?
2. if not, how would you go about solving this problem? It must be pretty common to avoid hard coding in all test cases

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually if you get wrapped `IO a` values in arguments then you're *probably* doing something wrong. Both `testMyLexer` and `myTest` can be pure, so instead of

```
testMyLexer :: IO FilePath -> Assertion
myTest :: [IO FilePath] -> Test
```

do

```
testMyLexer :: FilePath -> Assertion
myTest :: [FilePath] -> Test
```

Then it's just a matter of using bind from `getTestFiles` to extract your `[FilePath]`:

```
do
    files <- getTestFiles
    runTestTT $ myTest files
```